# Let $U$ be a universe. Use an element argument to prove the following statement. For all sets $A$ and $B$ in $P(U)$, $(A \cap B)\subseteq(A \cup B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently stuck attempting this question. The only way I know how to solving this question is simply via $(A \cap B)\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq(A \cup B)$. Therefore $(A \cap B)\subseteq(A \cup B)$.

However, as mentioned in the question I need to use an element argument to prove it. Anyone able to advice/teach me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Take any $x \in A\cap B$. Prove that this $x \in A \cup B$.

Comment: is thanasissdr's comment in the right direction, or is there something we are missing? and what is P(U)?

Comment: @thanasissdr; does it change the question then? or would $U$ suffice?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Basically, we have the equivalence:
$$A \subseteq U \iff A \in \mathcal{P}(U).$$

Comment: @thanasissdr; okay, i see, does this mean $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(U))=\mathcal{P}(U)$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry  No, that's not the case. Let $U = \{a,b,c\}$. The number of elements in $\mathcal{P}(U)$ is: $\left|\mathcal{P}(U)\right| = 2^3 = 8 $. However, $\left| \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(U))\right|= 2^8$. Consequently, $\mathcal{P}(U) \neq  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(U)).$

Comment: @thanasissdr; okay, so if the question was 'for all A,B in P(P(U))' it would be false?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, it would be still valid. We can rename the set $\mathcal P( \mathcal  P(U))$ to anything. E.g. $\mathcal P( \mathcal  P(U)) = Z$. We still have a set. Elements in $Z$ can be anything, like elements in $U$. All of $a,b,c \in U$ could be sets. Maybe [this](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66741.html) is a little helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
x\in A\cap B &\implies x\in A \land x\in B \\
 &\implies x\in A \\
 &\implies x\in A \lor x\in B \\
 &\implies x\in A\cup B
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the great help. However just to clarify the reason how do we derive from x∈A∧x∈B⟹x∈A? Is it showing that (A ∩ B)⊆A. Therefore x∈A∧x∈B⟹x∈A ? Right?

Comment: That is a purely logical statement, often assumed [or proven](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514035/proving-a-wedge-b-implies-a-in-propositional-calculus) in logical systems. Example: If I say "My name is Rory and I am married" you can then infer that "My name is Rory." The next line in my proof is another logical statement: You can also then infer that "My name is Rory or my name is George." I do not know which is your logical system, so I don't know what is an axiom for you and what you have derived.